# Relation between $H^1(M^3,Z_n)$ and $H^2(M^3,Z_n)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $M^3$ is a closed orientable manifold, then
$H^1(M^3,Z_n)$ and $H^2(M^3,Z_n)$ have the same number of elements if $n$ is a prime number, due to a duality relation. If $n$ is not prime and/or $M^3$ is not orientable, whether $H^1(M^3,Z_n)$ and $H^2(M^3,Z_n)$ still have the same number of elements.

In general, we can ask the similar question for $H^k(M^d,Z_n)$ and $H^{d-k}(M^d,Z_n)$.

Comment: I vote to migrate the question to MSE, since it is a standard question in a first course on homology and cohomology.

Comment: Would you tell us who are WE ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the groups $\text{H}^k(M^d, \mathbb{Z}_n)$ and $\text{H}^{d - k}(M^d, \mathbb{Z}_n)$ are isomorphic. It follows from Poincaré duality (shows the torsion part of $\text{H}^k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is $T_{d - k}$ which is the torsion of $\text{H}_{d - k}(M, \mathbb{Z})$) and the universal coefficient theorem (shows that the torsion part $\text{H}^k$ is $T_{k - 1}$) that $T_{k - 1} = T_{d - k}$. Then applying the universal coefficient theorem again to any abelian group $G$ (in your case $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$), you will find the claimed isomorphism.